# Distribution of subset-sums

Tags: pr.probability, additive-combinatorics

Let $A$ be a set of $n$ integers uniformly distributed in $\{0,\dots,N-1\}$. Let $S$ be the set of subset-sums modulo $N$ of $A$. Let $f_{n,N}(k)$ be the probability that $|S|=k$.

Is there an expression for $f_{n,N}(k)$? In particular, I am interested in the case where $N=2^n$.

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in this paper:

*Li, Jiyou; Wan, Daqing*, [**Counting subset sums of finite Abelian groups**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcta.2011.07.003), J. Comb. Theory, Ser. A 119, No. 1, 170-182 (2012). [ZBL1229.05289](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1229.05289).

Abstract:

> In this paper, we obtain an explicit formula for the number of zero-sum $k$-element subsets in any finite abelian group.

Comment: Thank you so much for improving this answer!